# How to ignore POJO Values only while taking the input from user not while sending the response

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot

Requirement: I want to ignore reading few parameters from the user input(JSON) but I want to include the same parameters in the response. Currently I have to the current code which is ignoring in both receiving and sending.

That is, While reading the user input it skips `Order Id, Order Status` etc and while sending the response JSON will not be having `Order Id, Order Status`. I want to skip while reading and I want to include while sending the response.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true, value = { "Order Id", "Order Status", "Created Date", "Last Modified" })
public class OrderDTO implements Serializable {


@JsonProperty("Order Id") 
private Long orderId;
@JsonProperty("Address")
AddressDTO addressDto;

@JsonProperty("Order Status")
private String status;
@JsonProperty(value = "Customer Id") 
@Size(min = 3, message = "Customer Id Should Be Greater Than 3 Characters")
@NotNull(message = "Customer Id Should Not Be Null.")
private String userId;
```

Your effort will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: can you please explain what you have tried and what problem you faced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 2.6: a more intuitive way is to use the `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty` annotation on the field. Try adding

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
private Long orderId;
```

Comment: Have one doubt, can I do this for only for post and skip for put and patch? Is there any way to do this? Because In Post I should not have this in entity and in Put i require this to persist.